# Defining and reusing an EL variable in JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

Is it possible to define variable and reuse the variable later in EL expressions ?

For example :

```
<h:inputText 
   value="#{myBean.data.something.very.long}"
   rendered="#{myBean.data.something.very.long.showing}"
/>
```

What i have in mind is something like :

```
<!-- 
     somehow define a variable here like : 
     myVar = #{myBean.data.something.very.long} 
-->
<h:inputText 
   value="#{myVar}"
   rendered="#{myVar.showing}"
/>
```

Any ideas ? Thank you !

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use [`<c:set>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/c/set.html) for this:

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="#{myBean.data.something.very.long}" scope="request" />
```

This EL expression will then be evaluated once and stored in the request scope. Note that this works only when the value is available during [view build time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense). If that's not the case, then you'd need to remove the `scope` attribtue so that it becomes a true "alias":

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="#{myBean.data.something.very.long}" />
```

Note thus that this **does not** cache the evaluated value in the request scope! It will be re-evaluated everytime.

Do **NOT** use `<ui:param>`. When not used in order to pass a parameter to the `template` as defined in `<ui:composition>` or `<ui:decorate>`, and thus in essence abusing it, then the behavior is unspecified and in fact it would be a bug in the JSF implementation being used if it were possible. This should never be relied upon. See also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Wow, thanks ! I thought ui:param only supplies a variable to be used in a template, which makes use of ui:composition. Does that mean every jsf page that i make is a facelet even though im not using ui:composition ?

Comment: @BalusC, what do you mean by don't cache the value ?

Comment: @Msaleh: Everytime you call `#{myVar}` then the `#{myBean.data.something.very.long}` will be re-evaluated. It will not be evaluated only once during the set. It's thus merely an "alias".

Comment: ok, it doesn't cache, but is there any reason why *it shouldn't* ?

Comment: @user: Because, by default, EL expressions may evaluate to a different value depending on the moment you invoke it. E.g. depending on the current phase, iteration status of a repeating component, etc. If you want to explicitly set it in request, view, session or application scope use as answered the `<c:set>`.

Comment: Somewhere there was a mention of `<ui:param>` to which bertie further refers, but is now gone. He is actually asking a very valid question: `<ui:param>` documents: "Use this tag to pass parameters to an included file (using ui:include), or a template (linked to either a composition or decorator). Embed ui:param tags in either ui:include, ui:composition, or ui:decorate to pass the parameters." - can we use `<ui:param>` outside that context? See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620210/744133

Comment: @YoYo: You can, but the behavior is unspecified and should absolutely not be relied on. It's in fact a bug in the JSF implementation if abusing <ui:param> as <c:set> would be possible. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3342984

Answer (score 19):

Like any view in MVC, the page should be as **simple as possible.** If you want a shortcut, put the shortcut into the **controller** (the `@ManagedBean` or `@Named` bean).

Controller:

```
@Named
public MyBean
{
    public Data getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public Foo getFooShortcut()
    {
        return data.getSomething().getVery().getLong();
    ]
}
```

View:

```
<h:inputText 
   value="#{myBean.fooShortcut}"
   rendered="#{myBean.fooShortcut.showing}"
/>
```

Comment: Perfect solution to grab my <p:dataTable> metadata objects from the backing bean. Thanks!