# Setting a variable in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have something like this in my jsf:

```
<div title="Percentage: #{myBean.numberToBeConvertedToPercentage}"></div>
```

I wanted to make something like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.numberToBeConvertedToPercentage}">
    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" type="percent"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Of course, not inside an output text, but instead setting the converted number to a variable, so I can use it inside my div. 
I don't want to take this converted number direct from my bean, since I use it in another places of my view without formatting it, and creating a get just for this, I don't like the idea. There is any way to make this only in my view?

Answer (score 1):

1. To go with `<h:outputText>` + converter, it is the best approach for this purpose in JSF. You can redesign your Html <del>to separate the label "Percentage: " and the data.</del>  to use rendered value in JS code to pass it to 'title' attribute.

   ```
   <div id="titleDiv" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#titleDiv').title = 'Percentage: <h:outputText value="#{myBean.numberToBeConvertedToPercentage}"><f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" type="percent"/></h:outputText>';
   </script>
   ```
2. If you still want to stay without converters, then you can create one more bean per your view and render values in get methods.
3. Other option is to use *EL 2.2 Method call* feature and to call your own format bean

   ```
   <div title="Percentage: #{formatBean.formatNumber(myBean.numberToBeConvertedToPercentage, 2)}"></div>
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure how #1 is ever possible in this construct. Do you mean to render the tooltip as a separate hidden `<div>`/`<span>` and show it using CSS/JS instead of using `title` attribute?

Comment: Oh .. I have missed that you need 'title', thought attribute name is not meaningful. In that case - yes, rendered data could be passed to JS, but I do not like number '1' now)

Comment: I'm almost getting tired and using some kind of the #2, using another getter like `getNumberToBeConvertedToPercentageAlreadyConverted` :P #3 looks too much of overkill for this case :P

Comment: @mudalov what's your idea if I use converters?

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked this, but maybe you can use ui:param and assign a converter to it.

and then use it in your page

```
<div title="Percentage: #{myVar}></div>
```

see [Defining and reusing an EL variable in JSF page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434866/defining-and-reusing-variable-in-jsf-page)

Comment: Tried that, but `myVar` comes with the original value, not with the converted value =(