# Any way to give an alias to long EL expressions?

Tags: jsf, el

Sometimes EL expressions go too long or otherwise I am forced to truncate names of my beans to make the EL easily readable. I was just wondering if there is a way I could give my long 4-5 level deep EL expressions just a simple alias or a variable name ? so that I could use that instead of repeating the whole expression repeatedly on page ?

I am truly frustrated with repeating long ELs like this:

```
#{profilesInteractionManager.profile.quickIntro.specializationAreas}
#{profilesInteractionManager.profile.quickIntro.interestAreas}
```

I was wondering if I could just do this instead:

```
#{prf.specializationAreas}
#{prf.interestAreas}
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: yes, added an example to question..

Comment: I wonder why you are repeating these EL expressions, maybe you can replace some code with `<ui:include />` or `<ui:composite />` etc so you don't have repeated code parts? Ortherwise, you are searching for [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434866/defining-and-reusing-variable-in-jsf-page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a ui:parm. e.g.

```
<ui:param name="quickIntro" value="#{profilesInteractionManager.profile.quickIntro.}" />
```

and then use: `#{quickIntro.specializationAreas}`, etc