# Avoid unnecessary function calls in JSF

Tags: performance, jsf

How can I avoid calling a function on my bean more than once if I have several HTML elements that call this function in their `rendered` attribute?

```
<h:outputText value="1" rendered="#{myBean.myFunc() eq 70}"/> 
<h:outputText value="2" rendered="#{myBean.myFunc() eq 42}"/>
```

Here, the second outputText will unnecessarily call myFunc() again. Is it possible to avoid this behavior?

Comment: You could store the result of myFunc() in a variable and use that instead. But then you need to call myFunc() yourself somewhere. Still that is what i would do.     But you could also use some sort of caching like ehcache, but that might be overkill.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining and reusing variable in JSF page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434866/defining-and-reusing-variable-in-jsf-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6441415/1695393) by BalusC provides a nice way to set and reuse variables in JSF.

Comment: what library is `<c:>`?

Comment: <c:> is the JSTL core taglib. [here is a link to docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/c/tld-summary.html)