# Evaluate EL expression from bean in JSF page

Tags: jsf, el, managed-bean

Is there any way to execute EL expression received from bean in JSF page?

Bean method

```
public class Bean {

    public String getExpr() {
        return "#{emtpy row.prop ? row.anotherProp : row.prop}";
    }

}
```

JSF page:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="row">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.expr}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: For my purpose, i've decide to wrapping entity with another class, where all view specific logic evaluated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use JSF [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) in getter to programmatically evaluate an EL expression on the current context. This is in this specific case only fishy as you're basically tight-coupling view logic in the controller/model.

```
public String getExpr() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{emtpy row.prop ? row.anotherProp : row.prop}", String.class);
}
```

Or use JSTL [`<c:set>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/c/set.html) (without `scope`!) in view to create an alias of an EL expression in the view in case your actual concern is the length of the EL expression.

```
<c:set var="expr" value="#{emtpy row.prop ? row.anotherProp : row.prop}" />

<p:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="row">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{expr}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Needless to say that JSTL way is way much cleaner.

#### See also:

- [Defining and reusing an EL variable in JSF page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434866/defining-and-reusing-an-el-variable-in-jsf-page)
- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, but You shouldn't do it in such way.

It should be done on JSF page if it is rendering, or it should be done as java logic in the service class if it is data processing.

It is really bad to do this kind of things (dynamically inject logic during rendering of JSF page), because it will make this code very difficult to maintain. I'm sure that there is better (more straight-forward, expressive and easier to understund for someone else) way of doing what you need.

It is just advice about creating good code, as your question apparently is about doing something that should be kept simple in very complicated way.

Comment: Main goal of this, is creating dynamic table (remove duplications of tables and logic that used them). I also thinking about wrapping entity with class, where all view specific logic will be kept. But i think there will be some cases, where this bad tricks works well

Comment: It is not clear for me what you wish to do. Please ask another question on stack overflow about how to do this 'creation of dynamic table', post some realted code you have, describe what you would like to achieve. I'am sure there will be plenty of answers how to do this in proper way without dynamic logic injetion into JSF.